# Restore files that where moved to trash

Tags: 12.04

I accidentally moved files in folder1 to trash. But I am not sure which files where in this folder so I cannot restore them one by one.

Does ubuntu still know that this files where placed in folder1? Can I restore those files back into the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open files, and navigate to trash, and change the view to list view, that will let you see the original location of the deleted files.  Just highlight the ones you want, and restore.

[image]

Comment: Glad that I could help.:)